# How to schedule the execution of broadcast tasks from a queue of to be broadcasted data with a one second delay in between each broadcast invocation?

Tags: javascript, async-await, scheduled-tasks, generator, scheduler

I have a task that runs every second like so:

```
let queue = ["Sample Data 1", "Sample Data 2"]
const job = schedule.scheduleJob('*/1 * * * * *', function () {
    console.log("Checking the queue...")
    if (queue.length > 0) {
        wss.broadcast(JSON.stringify({
            data: queue[0]
        }));
        setTimeout(() => {
            queue.shift();
        }, queue[0].duration);
    }
});
```

I am wondering how I can make it so that the timeout must finish before the next queue check. Could I use a de-bounce, or is there a better way?

Answer (score 0):

You could use

```
Math.max(queue[0].duration, 1000 - (performance.now() - start))
```

to make an interval between the jobs at least 1 second and call the schedule recursively.

In that case returning a job could make not much sense, so you could collect your jobs in an array for example if needed.

```js
const schedule = {
  scheduleJob(job, cb){
    setTimeout(cb, Math.random()*500);
    return job;
  }
};

const wss = {
  broadcast(task){  
    console.log(JSON.stringify(task));
  }
};

let queue = [{title: "Sample Data 1", duration: 2000}, {title: "Sample Data 2", duration: 500}];

const shiftQueue = (stopCb, jobs = []) => {
    if(!queue.length) return stopCb(jobs);
    const start = performance.now();
    const job = schedule.scheduleJob('*/1 * * * * *', function () {
      console.log("Checking the queue...")
      wss.broadcast(JSON.stringify({
          data: queue[0]
      }));
      setTimeout(() => {
          queue.shift();
          shiftQueue(stopCb, jobs);
      }, Math.max(queue[0].duration, 1000 - (performance.now() - start)));
    });
    jobs.push(job);
}

shiftQueue(jobs => console.log(jobs));
```

But I would use an async generator to simplify the logic. A bonus here that you can execute an async code with `await` in the `for await` loop and its execution time will be counted also:

```js
const schedule = {
  scheduleJob(job, cb){
    setTimeout(cb, Math.random()*500);
    return job;
  }
};

const wss = {
  broadcast(task){  
    console.log(JSON.stringify(task));
  }
};

let queue = [{title: "Sample Data 1", duration: 2000}, {title: "Sample Data 2", duration: 500}];

const timeout = timeout => new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, timeout));

async function* shiftQueue(queue){
    for(const task of queue){
      const start = performance.now();  
      const job = new Promise(resolve => {
        const job = schedule.scheduleJob('*/1 * * * * *', function () {
          console.log("Checking the queue...")
          wss.broadcast(JSON.stringify({
              data: task
          }));
          resolve(job);
        });
      });
      yield job;
      await timeout(Math.max(task.duration, 1000 - (performance.now() - start)));
    }
}

(async () => {
  for await(job of shiftQueue(queue)){
    console.log(job);
    // emulate some async work
    await timeout(100);
  }
  console.log('complete');
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

The OP's problem qualifies perfectly for a solution of mainly 2 combined techniques ...

1. the [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) based creation of a list of [async function/s (expressions)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/async_function), each function representing a delaying broadcast task (*delaying* and not *delayed* because the task executes immediately but delays its resolving/returning time).
2. the creation of an [async generator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/AsyncGenerator) via an [async generator-function (expression)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/async_function*), where the latter consumes / works upon the created list of delaying tasks, and where the async generator itself will be iterated via the [`for await...of` statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for-await...of).

In addition one needs to write kind of a `wait` function which can be achieved easily via an async function which returns a [`Promise`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/Promise) instance, where the latter resolves the promise via [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setTimeout) and a customizable delay value.

```js
const queueData =
  ["Sample Data 1", "Sample Data 2", "Sample Data 3"];

// create a list of async function based "delaying tasks".
const delayingTasks = queueData
  .map(data => async () => {

    wss.broadcast(
      JSON.stringify({ data })
    );
    await wait(1500);

    return `successful broadcast of "${ data }"`;
  });

// create an async generator from the "delaying tasks".
const scheduledTasksPool = (async function* (taskList) {
  let task;
  while (task = taskList.shift()) {

    yield await task();
  }
})(delayingTasks);

// utilize the async generator of "delaying tasks".
(async () => {
  for await (const result of scheduledTasksPool) {

    console.log({ result });
  }
})();
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

```html
<script>

const wss = {
  broadcast(payload) {
    console.log('broadcast of payload ...', payload);
  },
};

async function wait(timeInMsec = 1_000) {
  return new Promise(resolve =>
    setTimeout(resolve, Math.max(0, Math.min(timeInMsec, 20_000)))
  );
}

</script>
```

And since the approach is two folded, one even can customize each delay in between two tasks ... one just slightly has to change the format of the to be queued data and the task generating mapper functionality (2 lines of code are effected) ...

```js
// changed format.
const queueData = [
  { data: "Sample Data 1", delay: 1000 },
  { data: "Sample Data 2", delay: 3000 },
  { data: "Sample Data 3", delay: 2000 },
  { data: "Sample Data 4" },
];

// create a list of async function based "delaying tasks".
const delayingTasks = queueData
  .map(({ data, delay = 0 }) => async () => { // changed argument.

    wss.broadcast(
      JSON.stringify({ data })
    );
    await wait(delay); // changed ... custom delay.

    return `successful broadcast of "${ data }"`;
  });

// create an async generator from the "delaying tasks".
const scheduledTasksPool = (async function* (taskList) {
  let task;
  while (task = taskList.shift()) {

    yield await task();
  }
})(delayingTasks);

// utilize the async generator of "delaying tasks".
(async () => {
  for await (const result of scheduledTasksPool) {

    console.log({ result });
  }
})();
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

```html
<script>

const wss = {
  broadcast(payload) {
    console.log('broadcast of payload ...', payload);
  },
};

async function wait(timeInMsec = 1_000) {
  return new Promise(resolve =>
    setTimeout(resolve, Math.max(0, Math.min(timeInMsec, 20_000)))
  );
}

</script>
```